# how to get multiple paths between locations on a google map using fragment

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic3

this is the code I have used to draw a single path. Please provide me with useful details so that it will be helpful for me to locate different paths.

```ts
calculateAndDisplayRoute() {

    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;          
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;        
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 7,
                center: {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65}
              });

    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    directionsService.route({

        origin: this.start,      
        destination: this.end,     
        travelMode: 'DRIVING'     
    }, function(response, status) {

            if (status === 'OK') {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            } else {
                 window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
            }
    });

}

ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.calculateAndDisplayRoute();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `provideRouteAlternatives` property of the directions request object:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/directions#DirectionsRequest.provideRouteAlternatives

If you set this property to true the service will return up to 3 alternative routes between your points. Your code should be

```
directionsService.route({
    origin: this.start,      
    destination: this.end,     
    provideRouteAlternatives: true,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'     
}, function(response, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
             window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
});
```

I hope this helps!